# Getting TypeError: selector.includes is not a function when scraping with cheerio and jsonframe

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio, jsonframe-cheerio

I am trying to scrap a website with the following code:

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const jsonframe = require('jsonframe-cheerio');

const $ = cheerio.load('https://coinmarketcap.com/all/views/all/');
jsonframe($); // initializes the plugin

//exception handling 
process.on('uncaughtException', err =>
  console.error('uncaught exception: ', err))
process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, p) =>
  console.error('unhandled rejection: ', reason, p))

const frame = {
    "crypto": {         
        "selector": "tbody > tr",   
        "data": [{             
            "name": "td:nth-child(2) > a:nth-child(3)", 
            "url": {                                  
                "selector": "td:nth-child(2) > a:nth-child(3)",    
                "attr": "href"                     
            },
            "marketcap": "tr > td:nth-child(4)",
            "price": "tr > td:nth-child(5) > a:nth-child(1)", 
        }]
    }

};

let companiesList = $('tbody').scrape(frame);
console.log(companiesList);
```

However, I get an `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` when running the above example code:

```
(node:3890) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: selector.includes is not a function
```

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

**UPDATE**

I changed my code to the following below. However, I only can scrap the first element.

Any suggestions why the other elements do not get scrapped?

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const jsonframe = require('jsonframe-cheerio')
const got = require('got');


async function scrapCoinmarketCap() {
    const url = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/all/views/all/'
    const html = await got(url)
    const $ = cheerio.load(html.body)

    jsonframe($) // initializing the plugin

    let frame = {
        "Coin": "td.no-wrap.currency-name > a",
        "url": "td.no-wrap.currency-name > a @ href",
        "Symbol": "td.text-left.col-symbol",
        "Price": "td:nth-child(5) > a",
    }

    console.log($('body').scrape(frame, {
        string: true
    }))
}

scrapCoinmarketCap()
```

Comment: Which node version are you using?

Comment: What version of `jsonframe-cheerio` are you using? Judging from the syntax in your snippet, I suspect you're relying on documentation or example of version 1.x. The latest version 2.x introduced a lot of changes. The readme file includes this warning: _"Careful if you've been using jsonframe from the version 1.x.x, some things changed to make it more flexible, faster to use (inline parameters) and more meaningful in the syntax"._

Comment: @FelixKling I am using  `node --version` `v8.4.0`

Comment: @Boaz I am using `"cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.2"` and `"jsonframe-cheerio": ^3.0.1"`

Answer (score 6):

Based on your updated code, you can scrape all currency data by iterating on each `tr`:

```
$('body tr').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).scrape(frame, {
    string: true
  }))
})
```

However, I think the cleanest way to do this (as I said in [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47012544) answer) is to use *jsonframe-cheerio* [List/Array](https://github.com/gahabeen/jsonframe-cheerio#list--array) frame pattern, which is exactly intended to do that:

```
let frame = {
  currency: {
    _s: "tr",  // the selector
    _d: [{  // allow you to get an array of data, not just the first item
      "Coin": "td.no-wrap.currency-name > a",
      "Url": "td.no-wrap.currency-name > a @ href",
      "Symbol": "td.text-left.col-symbol",
      "Price": "td:nth-child(5) > a"
    }]
  }
}

console.log($('body').scrape(frame, {
  string: true
}))
```

Comment: Thx for your reply! One more questions, what would you recommend if I want to scrap also the subpage from the extracted URL? Do I need to run this through a `for-loop` or is there a better way within the `jsonframe` plugin?

Comment: Not sure but I don't think there is an existing option to do that. You will probably have to build your own recursive function.

Answer (score -1):

The method `cheerio.load()` does not accept URLs - **it requires the HTML as string.**

While I have not looked into the source code of cheerio, it would seem that the module tries to parse the URL as an HTML document which, obviously, fails and various errors start to appear.

To fix the problem, you need to first load the HTML content of that URL into a variable and then pass that HTML content to cheerio.

You can do that with modules like [`request`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) or [`got`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got).

Here's an example of loading the page using `got`:

```
const got = require('got')
const cheerio = require('cheerio')

got('https://google.com')
.then(res => {
  const $ = cheerio.load(res.body)
  // Continue as usual
})
.catch(console.error)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I kindly ask you if your minimum viable example could show the scrapping of the example link in my question.

Comment: I am quite certain you can copy/paste your original scraping code into the `// continue as usual`-commented block. You were using cheerio incorrectly - just try it out the right way and I am sure you will figure out the rest!

Comment: I tried your code, and I still get the same error as displayed above!

Comment: Just fixed the above code. However, `cheerio` only scrapes the first element. Any suggestions why this is the case?