# Scraping all rows from a table with cheerio

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I am running the below code to scrape data. However, the code only scrapes the first element.

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const jsonframe = require('jsonframe-cheerio')
const got = require('got');

async function scrapeCoinmarketCap() {
    const url = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/all/views/all/'
    const html = await got(url)
    const $ = cheerio.load(html.body)

    jsonframe($) // initializing the plugin

    let frame = {
        "Coin": "td.no-wrap.currency-name > a",
        "url": "td.no-wrap.currency-name > a @ href",
        "Symbol": "td.text-left.col-symbol",
        "Price": "td:nth-child(5) > a",
    }

    console.log($('body').scrape(frame, {
        string: true
    }))
}

scrapeCoinmarketCap()

//Output -> only the first element
//    {
//      "Coin": "Bitcoin",
//      "url": "/currencies/bitcoin/",
//      "Symbol": "BTC",
//      "Price": "$6122.67"
//    }
```

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see the point of doing it this way. If you scrape it the regular way you can test it in your browser console and tweak it until you get it right.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all currency data with the [List / Array](https://github.com/gahabeen/jsonframe-cheerio#list--array) pattern:

```
let frame = {
  currency: {
    _s: "tr",
    _d: [{
      "Coin": "td.no-wrap.currency-name > a",
      "url": "td.no-wrap.currency-name > a @ href",
      "Symbol": "td.text-left.col-symbol",
      "Price": "td:nth-child(5) > a"
    }]
  }
}

console.log($('body').scrape(frame, {
  string: true
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

`got` and `jsonframe-cheerio` are deprecated. Avoid them.

Here's how to do this with standard fetch and cheerio code (fetch is native in Node 18+, and cheerio has 7,870,278 weekly downloads at the current time, so it's 655,856 times more popular than jsonframe-cheerio's 12 weekly downloads).

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // ^1.0.0-rc.12

const url = "<Your URL>";

fetch(url)
  .then(res => {
    if (!res.ok) {
      throw Error(res.statusText);
    }

    return res.text();
  })
  .then(html => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);
    const data = [...$("table:last").find("tr:has(td)")].map(e => ({
      coin: $(e).find("td:nth-child(2)").text(),
      url: $(e).find("td:nth-child(2) a").attr("href"),
      symbol: $(e).find("td:nth-child(3)").text(),
      price: $(e).find("td:nth-child(5)").text(),
    }));
    console.log(data.slice(0, 20));
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Output:

```js
[
  {
    coin: 'BTCBitcoin',
    url: '/currencies/bitcoin/',
    symbol: 'BTC',
    price: '$70,271.61'
  },
  {
    coin: 'ETHEthereum',
    url: '/currencies/ethereum/',
    symbol: 'ETH',
    price: '$3,606.56'
  },
  {
// ...
```

Note that at the time of writing, prices are loaded asynchronously beyond the first 20 or so, so if you want those details, consider using a browser automation library like Puppeteer, or look into making API calls.